# Create Out-File-names using array elements

Tags: powershell

I need to create .txt/.sap files/shortcuts with changing content. I use a do until loop and the file names should be created with strings from an array. I cannot use the square brackets to access the array because Powershell interprets them as a wild card characters.

The following code shows the principle:

```
$strSAPSystems = @("Production", "Finance", "Example")

$i = 0
do{
"text1" | Out-File .\SAP_$strSAPSystems[$i].sap
"text2" | Out-File .\SAP_$$strSAPSystems[$i].sap -Append
$i++
}
until($i -eq $strSAPSystems.length)
```

results in an error: "out-file : cannot perform operation because the wildcard path ... did not resolve to a file"

I tried to add the -literalPath parameter but it didn't work. I am new to Powershell, is there a better way to have the files named after the SAP systems?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the string(path) inside a subexpression `$(.....)` to extract the value of a single element in an array. Atm. the path becomes something like `.SAP_Production Finance Example[$i].sap`.

Also, you have an extra `$` in the second `Out-File`. Personally I would rewrite everthing to:

```
$strSAPSystems = @("Production", "Finance", "Example")

$strSAPSystems | ForEach-Object {
    "text1" | Out-File ".\SAP_$($_).sap"
    "text2" | Out-File ".\SAP_$($_).sap -Append"
}
```

`$_` is the current item in the array, and since it's a single object, I don't really need the subexpression `$()`, but I included it because it easier to see static and dynamic parts of the path.

Comment: Thank you Frode F. That is a much smarter way to do it. I will have a closer look into subexpressions as well though, to better understand how that works.